# как временно отключить onTouchListener()?

Tags: java

как в коде отключить `onTouchListener()`на заданное время в миллисекундах?

java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете передать в метод `setOnTouchListener()` null. Или можете отключить вашу View. Для того, чтоб через нужное время вам ее опять включить можно создать таймер выпоняющийся в фоновом потоке, который по окончанию выполнения будет возвращать все обратно.

А вообще нужно видеть код. Вы предоставили очень мало информации.